# Create MSysIMEX* ms-access tables proggramatically

Tags: delphi, ms-access-2010, dao, adox

I want to create a link with MS-Access MDB database with a txt file **via Delphi**.

MSysIMEXSpecs and MSysIMEXColumns are system tables with link properties (column separator etc), but these tables are only created by Access assistant.

Is there a way to create these tables programmatically? (with ADO, ADOX, DAO, DDL...)

Comment: You can use `ADOQuery` to create a table

Comment: I can't create System Tables with ADOQuery.

Comment: In MSAccess, there are 3 types of table (excluding links): TABLE, SYSTEM TABLE and ACCESS TABLE. TABLE are user-defined tables. SYSTEM TABLE has information of access internal controls (forms, relationships etc). ACCESS TABLE has extra info, and are not required in DB. MSysIMEXSpecs and MSysIMEXColumns are ACCESS TABLE. This information can be read in table properties via ADOX, but it's read-only.

Comment: In VBA, I can call SysCmd (555) to generate these tables. But, I can't call it in Delphi